# How can I tell when windows XP service pack 3 was applied to my machine

Tags: windows-xp, sp3

I'm trying to explain some "curious" behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way I can think of (If you do not have it in the event log) is to go to `c:\windows\$NtServicePackUninstall$` and poke around in sub directories - I think you want `spuninst` and look at file creation dates.

I only have a Windows 2003 machine I can test this on and it shows what date I installed Service Pack 2 on:

[image]

Comment: This appears to work for me on XP Pro.  C:\WINDOWS\$NtServicePackUninstall$\spuninst\spuninst.txt looks like a log file of the SP3 upgrade, created 6/3/2008

Comment: +1 Even better! Forgot about that log! Feel a bit stupid now!

Answer (score 1):

When you installed Service Pack 3, it may have created a System Restore Point.

Have a look for one in Start > Accessories > System Tools > System Restore

Answer (score 1):

Start Control Panel / Add or Remove Programs.
Click to select the Show Updates check box.
The date should be indicated next to the "Windows XP Service Pack 3" entry.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Vista (and, I assume, Windows 7) have a nice happy interface that tells you all that information. Very handy.

For XP, no such thing exists, so you might want to look at some third party tools. There is a piece of freeware caled [WinUpdatesList](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wul.html) that might solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to tell when SP3 was actually installed is to go to the Windows Update site.  On the left hand side there will be an item "Review your update history"  Click that and you will get a definitive list of what updates were installed and on what day.

On my (virtual) machine there is a specific entry for "Windows XP Service Pack 3 (KB936929)"

Keep in mind that there have been like 50 updates since SP3 so you may have to go back a while... Just keep clicking the "Next" button until SP3 is in the list.  On my machine it was a little confusing to get to it but until the "Next" button disappears you're not at the end of the list.